# Bootrstrap grid layout not working on four gridview tables C#

Tags: c#, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with bootrstrap trying to get a grid system working. The first four divs take up 6 columns out of the 12 which works fine. The issue I am having is I want the next four divs (seventhdiv, eigthdiv, ninethdiv and tenthdiv) to take up six columns, however I want to make sure the gridviews inside each div are joint together so no padding on the left and right. I want all gridviews combined together and take up the rest of the page (remaining 6 columns out of the 12 for that row). Currently if I set col-sm-0 class on each div they are combined together but they dont take up the full width. If i set col-sm-2 they are spaced out with padding on either end.
How can I format this correctly using bootrstrap grid layout?

```
    <div class="row">
   <div id="thirddiv" class="col-sm-0">
   </div>
   <div id="fourthdiv" class="col-sm-2">
      <div id="dvTable" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="fifthdiv" class="col-sm-2">
      <div id="dvTable2" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="sixthdiv" class="col-sm-2">
      <div id="dvTable3" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
   </div>

   //ISSUE HERE ONWARDS
   <div id="seventhdiv" style="padding-left:15px" class="col-sm-0">
      <asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
         <Columns>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_name" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"   />
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_value" />
         </Columns>
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"></EditRowStyle>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" ></HeaderStyle>
         <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"></RowStyle>
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
      </asp:GridView>
   </div>
   <div id="eigthdiv" class="col-sm-0">
      <asp:GridView ID="GV2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="dt-responsive display compact">
         <Columns>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_name" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"  />
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_value"/>
         </Columns>
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"></EditRowStyle>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
         <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"></RowStyle>
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
      </asp:GridView>
   </div>
   <div id="ninethdiv" class="col-sm-0">
      <asp:GridView ID="GV3" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="dt-responsive display compact">
         <Columns>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_name" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"  />
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_value"/>
         </Columns>
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"></EditRowStyle>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
         <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"></RowStyle>
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
      </asp:GridView>
   </div>
   <div id="tenthdiv" class="col-sm-0">
      <asp:GridView ID="GV4" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="dt-responsive display compact">
         <Columns>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_name" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"  />
            <asp:boundfield datafield="column_value"/>
         </Columns>
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"></EditRowStyle>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C1E37" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
         <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"></RowStyle>
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
      </asp:GridView>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting) feature to achieve this along with the use of the [no-gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters) class (introduced in In Bootstap 4).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">1st</div>
    <div class="col-1">2nd</div>
    <div class="col-1">3rd</div>
    <div class="col-1">4th</div>
    <div class="col-1">5th</div>
    <div class="col-1">6th</div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-3">7th</div>
            <div class="col-3">8th</div>
            <div class="col-3">9th</div>
            <div class="col-3">10th</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```